# Android Null Object References on BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() and startscan()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create a BLE android app, and I've been having a lot of trouble with null pointers that I can't figure out even when using androids sample apps of android-BluetoothAdvertisements and android-BluetoothLEGatt.

This is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private ScanCallback mScanCallback;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private BluetoothDevice mBluetoothGatt;
    private String mDeviceName;
    private String mDeviceAddress;
    private ScanResultAdapter mAdapter;
    private BluetoothGattDescriptor mDescriptor;
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mBluetoothCharacteristic;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
    private BluetoothLeScanner btScanner;
    private BluetoothDevice mbluetoothDevice;
    Button button;



    DrawerLayout dLayout;
    private Button ble_scan;

    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;
    private final String LIST_NAME = "NAME";
    private final String LIST_UUID = "UUID";
    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
    public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";


    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

    // Stops scanning after 5 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 5000;


    //On entering app protocols
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        mDeviceName = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
        mDeviceAddress = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        //Set View and new Handler
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mAdapter = new ScanResultAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(),
                LayoutInflater.from(this));


        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        //sets up variables to initialize Bluetooth Manager and our Adapter settings
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        //Initializes Navigation Drawer
        setNavigationDrawer();

        //Checks if Bluetooth adapter is enabled and requests to enable it
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }


        //Initializes Scan Button
        //addListenerOnButton();
        //startScanning();


        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ScanOut);
        txtView.setText(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_NAME);



        //Initializing floating action button
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }








    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    /**
     * Custom ScanCallback object - adds to adapter on success, displays error on failure.
     */
    private class SampleScanCallback extends ScanCallback {

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results);

            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                mAdapter.add(result);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);

            mAdapter.add(result);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scan failed with error: " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start scanning for BLE Advertisements (& set it up to stop after a set period of time).
     */
    public void startScanning() {
        if (mScanCallback == null) {

            // Will stop the scanning after a set time.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopScanning();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            // Kick off a new scan.
            mScanCallback = new SampleScanCallback();
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Started Scan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Already Scanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop scanning for BLE Advertisements.
     */
    public void stopScanning() {

        // Stop the scan, wipe the callback.
        mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        mScanCallback = null;

        // Even if no new results, update 'last seen' times.
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


   /* private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {

        //mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;

                    mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);

            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }*/

    private void GattConnect() {

        BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = mbluetoothDevice.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();

        List<BluetoothGattService> services = mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
        for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
        }

    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            // this will get called anytime you perform a read or write characteristic operation
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
            // this will get called when a device connects or disconnects
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {
            // this will get called after the client initiates a            BluetoothGatt.discoverServices() call
        }
    };

    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
            mInflator = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
            return mLeDevices.get(position);
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();
            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText("Unknown Device");
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

            return view;
        }
    }




    /*


    Setting up Navigational Drawer that creates other fragments


     */
    private void setNavigationDrawer() {

        Intent intent = null;
        dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); // initiate a DrawerLayout
        NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation); // initiate a Navigation View

        // implement setNavigationItemSelectedListener event on NavigationView
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                Fragment frag = null; // create a Fragment Object
                int itemId = menuItem.getItemId(); // get selected menu item's id

                // check selected menu item's id and replace a Fragment Accordingly
                if (itemId == R.id.nav_home){
                    frag = new HomeFragment();
                } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_alarms) {
                    frag = new AlarmFragment();
                } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_cues) {
                    frag = new CueFragment();
                } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_data) {
                    frag = new DataFragment();
                } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_settings){
                    frag = new SettingFragment();
                } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_help){
                    frag = new HelpFragment();
                }
                // display a toast message with menu item's title
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (frag != null) {
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, frag); // replace a Fragment with Frame Layout
                    transaction.commit(); // commit the changes
                    dLayout.closeDrawers(); // close the all open Drawer Views
                    return true;
                }

                return false;

            }
        });
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //scanLeDevice(true);

            }

        });

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }


    //What happens on resuming the app
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
        // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        // Initializes list view adapter.
        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        //setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
        //scanLeDevice(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //scanLeDevice(false);
        mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



}
```

I am using the BluetoothLeService class from the Gatt example. Right now I am trying to get my scanning to work so I can find my BLE device to attempt to set up a Gatt connection with it.

I have tried implementing many parts of the examples, and since startLeScan() and stopLeScan() are depreciated, I am attempting to merge the BLE scanning from the bluetooth advertisements  example with the BLE Gatt example. The apps examples work fine, but I get a bunch of null pointers when I try to do it myself.

On my onResume function I will get this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()' on a null object reference`

Which is weird because I invoke the same method during onCreate without problems.

The thing that hasn't been working at all no matter how I try to invoke it is my startScanning method. I always get this error: 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method `void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference` because it seems like the startScan method never actually works. Maybe I am just doing something horribly wrong.

It's called in a fragment in the example, but I don't think that should affect it and I should be able to use it in my main activity for a base level connection for debugging if I'm not mistaken.

Does anyone have any advice on what I'm doing glaringly wrong?

Comment: have u seen this https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=MultiFinder-master/app/src/main/java/com/jinsen/multifinder/MainActivity.java

Comment: I have not seen that example, but it still uses the depreciated startLeScan() and stopLeScan like every example I have found.